# Django: AttributeError

Tags: python, django

```
class EventDeleteView(generic.FormView):
    form_class = EventDeleteForm
    template_name = 'event/event_delete.html'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
   ---> self.event = Event.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
   ---> kwargs['pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
```

What I do not understand is why `self.kwargs['pk']` in the `get_form_kwargs(self)` method works and why it does not work in the constructor.

I get this error: `'EventDeleteView' object has no attribute 'kwargs'`

Comment: Well the error suggests this has nothing to do with `kwargs`, but with `anmeldung`. Please provide a MWE that reproduces the error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I've updated the post.

Comment: You return `None` in your `get_form_kwargs(self):`, try adding `return kwargs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because `self.kwargs` is set in the view function returned from `.as_view` and not in the base class constructor.